# Class method from another class is never called

Tags: objective-c, class, methods, xcode4.5, user-defined-functions

I am trying to call method from one class in another class.

```
    @interface example : NSObject 
         -(void)displayString:(NSString*)str;
    @end

    @implementation example
         -(void)displayString:(NSString*)str
         {
             NSLog(@"The string:%@",str);
         }
    @end
   // callExample.h
   @interface callExample:UIViewController
        @property (nonatomic, strong) example *ex;
   @end
```

//the function displayString is called in this button pressed.

```
   // callExample.m
   @implementation callExample

       - (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)btn
       {
          [self.ex displayString:@"sampleTEXT"];
       }
   @end
```

so when i debug the `[self.ex displayString:@"sampleTEXT"];`, this line of code doesnot call the function in example class. I think i am doing everything correctly. i am missing something. where am i going wrong?

any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

First off, `displayString` is not a class method, it's an instance method. Second, and related, you don't create an instance of your `example` class to call the method on.

Let's put it in the `viewDidLoad` method for `callExample` class for now (you don't say if an instance already exists). Something like:

```
self.ex = [[example alloc] init];
```

Also, check the naming conventions please: [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html).